# Best way to pair turtles in netlogo

Tags: graph-theory, netlogo

I need to link every turtle to exactly 1 if possible (effectively have every turtle play a 2 player game round, so each link is a game with 2 players - but players can only play 1 game per tick or round).

What I've come up with is

```
ask turtles [
    ;; If I haven't gotten a link yet
    ifelse not any? link-neighbors [ 
      ;; setup a link with a different turtle that also doesn't have a link
      ;; roll a die to set up who wins or loses
      create-link-with one-of other turtles with [not any? link-neighbors] [set game-roll random-float 1.0]
    ]
  ]
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I think agentsets don't dynamically update so once the ask begins it's set is finalized which is why this is a bit strange

Comment: Suggestion: separate your pairing-up logic and your game playing.

Comment: The only game playing here is the the set game-roll which...I guess I could delay but doesn't seem that much of a complication

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: It just allows you to change your pairing up in any way you find you like better in the future, without changing the rest of your code.  For example, you might find that although your approach is fine logically (except for the incomplete ifelse), it takes too long with many turtles. Or you might find you need to accommodate an odd number of turtles. Etc.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty clean to me. Each turtle will get paired up an each pair will play the game exactly once. 
And since agentsets indeed don't dynamically update one the ask has begun, using an `if` inside the `ask` is the best way to ensure that the updated condition doesn't screw anything up

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I got your question right. Why do you want your agentset to update dynamically? I assume you don't want to unnecessarily loop through all turtles that have already created a link in a previous loop? One way could be, to first compute the number of pairs and use `repeat` to establish them.

```
let n_pairs floor (count turtles / 2)

repeat n_pairs [
  ask one-of turtles with [not any? link-neighbors] [
    create-link-with one-of other turtles with [not any? link-neighbors][
      set game-roll random-float 1.0
    ]
  ]
]
```

Hope that helps. Otherwise you might need to clarify your question.